# Cannot intercept user denying permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

My current application has a `FeedbackFragment`, which uses `Fragment` from the support library and provides a checkbox to allow the user to optionally send system logs with their feedback.  Because the attaching of the logs to the outgoing email requires access to external storage (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission), I must ask for permission at the time the `FeedbackFragment` is asked for.  If the user denies permission to write to external storage, I want to disable/hide the 'Include system logs' checkbox, but I want the remainder of the functionality for this screen to work (which works fine on pre-Marshmallow devices, BTW).  I have written the appropriate methods based on the official Android documentation for this, plus a combination of many SO articles, and this is what I currently have.  Note that I do not stop at any breakpoints in the 'deny' branches in this code.

All of the logic below gets created in a call to `checkExternalStoragePermissions()` from `onCreateView()`

What am I missing?

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        canSendAttachments = true;
        systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        requestExternalStoragePermission();
    }

}

private void requestExternalStoragePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        new SnackBar.Builder(getActivity())
                .withMessage(getString(R.string.write_external_storage_permission_rationale))
                .withDuration(SnackBar.PERMANENT_SNACK)
                .withActionMessage("OK")
                .withOnClickListener(new SnackBar.OnMessageClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessageClick(Parcelable token) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                    }
                })
                .withTextColorId(R.color.almanac_red_tab_highlight)
                .show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
        if ((grantResults.length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            canSendAttachments = true;
            systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            canSendAttachments = false;
            systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(false);
            systemLogsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: "Because the attaching of the logs to the outgoing email requires access to external storage" that may not actually be true - have you looked into using a ContentProvider?

Comment: Does going this route negate the need for the permission?  I was not aware that `ContentProviders` could be used to read/write text files.  Any examples?

Comment: The point is to avoid passing your data as a literal file.  The source data might still be an internal file to you, but not to the recipient app, therefore storage permission is not required.

Comment: I was able to take some time last night to look at this, and I still am not seeing how this is supposed to be done without the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.  I have gotten a ContentProvider written (first one, so keep that in mind) to be able to attach a file, but the file has to be created in order for the provider to attach it.  Again, do you have an example you can point me to that will do as you suggest?

Comment: Use an internal storage file in your app's private data folder (or even a non-file data structure) to back your ContentProvider.  Also I believe you will find that there is a way to make app-private external storage files without external storage permission (which you could use for the backing storage, not as a sharing mechanism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While **@iagreen** had an answer that was close, the issue I was having initially was caused by the fact that I was using the `ActivityCompat` version of the appropriate methods in my code.  Once I removed that prefix from the method calls and used the corresponding methods from the `Fragment` class, everything works as I expect now and the original issue has been resolved.

Having said that, I am also looking into how I can possibly use a `ContentProvider` to negate the need for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission altogether, as suggested by **@Chris Stratton**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling from a `Fragment`, you should call [`FragmentCompat.requestPermissions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html#requestPermissions%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String[],%20int%29) so the callback get routed your fragment instead of your activity.

You may need to add this to your gradle file since `FragmentCompat` is in the support-v13 lib.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

Comment: This option will not work for me, as the method you mention does not allow me to use the `Fragment` class in the support library.  I have updated the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implement `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` `Listener` of `ActivityCompat` class in your `Activity` and override  `void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)` Method to check whether User is allowing or denying the permission

You can do like this:

```
int REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;

private void checkExternalStoragePermissions() {
    if (hasStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        canSendAttachments = true;
        systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        requestExternalStoragePermission();
    }
}

public boolean hasStoragePermissionGranted(){
        return  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public void requestExternalStoragePermission() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Here is `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method will be called when user allow or deny Permission from Runtime permission dialog.

You can also handle situation when User has checked never show Runtime Permission dialog.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //Storage permission is enabled
               canSendAttachments = true;
               systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivtity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //User has deny from permission dialog
                Snackbar.make(mainLayout, getResources().getString("Please enable storage permission"),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_STORAGE);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            } else {
                // User has deny permission and checked never show permission dialog so you can redirect to Application settings page
                Snackbar.make(mainLayout, getResources().getString("Please enable permission from settings"),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.